# Заменить элементы строки на значения словаря

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, с задачей. Есть строка

```
st = 'qwqewqewqeggghhhvvvvbvc'
```

Есть словарь

```
x = {a:3, d:5, g:8}
```

нужно проверить строку на наличие символов равным ключам словаря и если таковые имеются заменить символ в строке на значение в словаре. Что-то

```
for i in st:
   if x.keys() in st:
```

Вот дальше просто не совсем понимаю, как написать. Если `x.keys() in st`, тогда...

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from string import maketrans

def replace_text(text, valc):
    """
    >>> text = 'abcdefg'
    >>> valc = {'a': 1, 'g': 2}
    >>> print replace_text(text, valc)
    1bcdef2
    """
    frm = ''.join([str(i) for i in valc.keys()])
    to = ''.join([str(i) for i in valc.values()])
    trantab = maketrans(frm, to)
    return text.translate(trantab)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Не сочтите за наглость, если не трудно объясните вот этот момент:

    if __name__ == '__main__':

    import doctest

    doctest.testmod()

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html

Если заметили, в документации метода replace_text присутствует код, который будет выполнен в интерактивном режиме. doctest.testmod() выполняет тесты, присутсвующие в документации метода.

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой код в голову пришел. Можно адаптировать ко многому. Единственно не уверен в скорости работы присваивания строкового.

```
text = 'qwqewqewqeggghhhvvvvbvc'
x = {'a':3, 'd':5, 'g':8}

for key in x.keys():
    text = text.replace(key, str(x[key]))

print(text)
```

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь, очень сильно помогло!))

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий вариант он будет заменять только те буквы которые есть в списке х1 на те что в х2

```
x1 = ("a","d","g","v");  
x2 = ("3","5","8","2");

text = "qwqewqewqeggghhhvvvvbvc"

for i in range(0, len(x1)):
 re1 = x1[i]
 re2 = x2[i]

 text = text.replace(re1, '--')
 text = text.replace(re2, re1)
 text = text.replace('--', re2)

print text
```